# Use a class function from a nested component without @Output property

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Does anyone know how to use a class's instantiation (and not create another instance) from a nested component inside of this very class ?

To be clearer : I have a component and class named AppBar that contains a component Authenticator and I'd like to use an Appbar's function inside of the Authenticator (kind of returning a value to the AppBar without using @Output property). And the trick is to keep the AppBar to only one instance because otherwise I get a null exception since the component isn't being instantiate properly and is not the same as the one that contains the Authenticator. I hope I'm clear, otherwise I'll try my best to explain it better.

Thanks by advance.

Here is the AppBar Class

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/content/deferred_content.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

import '../../utils/init/authenticator.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'app_bar',
  templateUrl: 'app_bar.html',
  styleUrls: ['package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    'app_bar.css'
  ],
  directives: [
    Authenticator,
    coreDirectives,
    formDirectives,
  ],providers: [
    ClassProvider(Authenticator),
],
)

class AppBar implements OnInit{

  HtmlElement avatar = querySelector("#avatar");

  @ViewChild('myAuthenticator')
  Authenticator authenticator;

    //This is the function to use from the nested component
  setIcon(String text,String email) {
    avatar.setAttribute("src",text);
    avatar.setAttribute("title",email);


  }

  void ngOnInit(){

  }

}
```

And here is the Authenticator one :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/plus/v1.dart';
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart";

import '../../components/app_bar/app_bar.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'authenticator',
  templateUrl: 'authenticator.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  directives: [
    AppBar,
    coreDirectives,
  ],
  providers: [
    ClassProvider(AppBar),
  ],
)

class Authenticator implements OnInit{

  Person loggedUser;

  @override
  void ngOnInit(){
    log.info("Initialisation of the Authenticator");
      ...
  }

...
...

  Future<Person> initUser(AutoRefreshingAuthClient client) async {
    Person person = await auth.getPlusUser(client);
    if (person != null) {
      printAccountEmailInfo(person);
      loggedUser = person;
        //This is where the AppBar shouldn't be re-created but use the same as the one from the directives
      AppBar().setIcon(person.image.url,auth.getPlusAccountEmail(person).value);
    }
    return person;
  }

}
```

Comment: Some code example would make it easier to understand.

Comment: You should be able to inject `AppBar` to `Authenticator` if you change `visibility` of `AppBar`, but the right approach would probably be to move that function you want to use to a service instead.

Comment: You're right, I updated so it's easier to see, the function I try to use is setIcon. I don't know anything about visibility of a component, what is it? You mean making a dependency injection of AppBar inside Authenticator ?

Comment: If you register components as providers, instances of the components plain class are created (without the component part). This is hardly ever what you want. A provider for a component makes only sense if you want a "redirecting" provider (`useClass`). What you want is to change `visibility` of the component you want to inject. The injector knows about parent components automatically if visibility is not hidden.

Comment: https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/Visibility-class

Comment: I still suggest using a shared service for communication between components that are not direct parent/child (where you can't use template bindings)

Comment: This shared communication service seems a good idea, do you have any example I could look into ? thanks for your help by the way, really appreciate it.

Comment: No, but I'd expect webdev.dartlang.org to provide some. If you're stuck I'd suggest to just ask again (a more focused question) here on SO.

Comment: Alright no problem, will do :) Thanks again.

Comment: Just a correction from above "redirecting" provider (`useClass`)." should have been `useExisting`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from the comments. Gunter answered it correctly, but moving it here for others:

> You should be able to inject AppBar to Authenticator if you change visibility of AppBar, but the right approach would probably be to move that function you want to use to a service instead.
>
> What you want is to change visibility of the component you want to inject. The injector knows about parent components automatically if visibility is not hidden.